Villains aren't born they're made
I've just been writing an essay on the fact that some villains in books might not actually be true villains and vice versa. While researching I've come across this phrase several times
"Villains aren't born they're made". 
I'm curious as to whether it comes from a movie/anime/tv-show (or a book/manga). Any advice (even if its to the contrary) is much appreciated.

To clarify are you asking if the phrase "villains aren't born but they're made" is inspired from movies/anime?

I want to say it's a joker (Heath Ledger) quote from Dark Night...

@BenPlont: Are you alluding to Harvey Dent's quote of "You either die a hero, or live long enough to become the villain"? Joker somewhat proves that point (without explicitly having heard that quote made by Harvey), but didn't actually say it.

@Flater, no, I'm remembering a Joker quote (or misremembering) - in the Killing Joke it was something like: one bad day will make you a bad guy...

Megamind (link) has one of its taglines as 

Heroes aren't born... they're made.

Given how Megamind flips the hero/villain archetype upside down, is it possible you're referring to this catchphrase?
Edit
It was also on posters (link) for the movie.

I'd say that this phrase is simply a rewording of 'nature vs. nurture'.
Basically, if a person grows up in a moral, law abiding family where he/she is taught to uphold the law, they won't grow up to be a villan.
But... if a person grows up in the company of 'villans' then the acts of villany will become the norm to them and their moral compass will be skewed towards criminal behaviour.
(this is the 'nuture' argument)
The other side of this argument (the 'nature' argument) is people are what they are born to be and no amount of guidance while young will change this.
Beyond this there are known mental disorders that prevent people from distinguishing right from wrong. In which case no amount of 'nuture' is going to help them. Serial killers are a good example of this (especially serial killers in the media).
You might be able to find the first use of the phrase but I doubt all subsquent uses are derived from that.

There is a similar quote from Iron Man 3 that might be of interest.
'We create our own demons.'

[first lines]
Tony Stark: [Narrates] A famous man once said, 'We create our own
  demons.' Who said that? What does that even mean? Doesn't matter. I
  said it 'cause he said it. So now, he was famous and that basically
  getting said by two well-known guys. I don't, uh... I'm gonna start
  again.
[pause]
Tony Stark: Let's track this from the beginning.

While this may not be the exact same quote but the context was the same. He was referring to the story of how one of his negligent actions gave birth to his nemesis.
source: IMDB quotes

We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Can you provide a reference?

Thanks @Panther for the guidance. I am including the reference.
